# How expensive is it to require() something within an Express.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express.js web app that is serving one of my domains. The `app.js` file looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// and so on…
```

I would like to use one of my own functions within the `app.js` file, so I thought I'd put the function in a separate file (as a module, i.e. `module.exports =` stuff) and then require it in the `app.js` file:

```
var myfunc = require('./path/to/myfunc');
```

However, I am worried about performance. Is there a significant performance penalty when requiring files inside an Express.js app? I guess this question boils down to how many times the `app.js` code is executed - once per HTTP request for my domain or only once during initialization, and whether or not the `require()` result is cached somehow between HTTP requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code you `require` is fetched and executed **a single time**. After that, you get back whatever was in `module.exports`, or `exports`.

Whenever a second call to `require` requests what is at the same location, it gets the same reference to `module.exports`, or `exports`.

In your particular case, code `require`d while bootstrapping the application is `require`d once, while bootstrapping.

Then, whenever a request `require`s something that hasn't been `require`d yet, it gets fetched and executed. Every single time after that, `require` calls will just fetch the cached data.

Remember how node is single threaded? That's why if you try to `require` a file that doesn't really exist, you'll bring the entire process down.

### Update

Answering Šime's question, about "when" `require` calls are executed.

`require` calls are executed as they are met when following the code, there's no pre-processing or any fancy magic like that. Everything that's not part of a request is effectively "shared" by the whole process, if it has access to that scope.

Let's look at an example. Suppose this is your `app.js`, and I'm ignoring all the irrelevant express bootstrapping code, for brevity.

```
var a = require('./foo.js'); // [1]

app.get('/thing', function (req, res, next) {
    next(); // [2]
});

app.get('/thing', function (req, res, next) {
    res.end();
});

app.get('/foo', function (req, res, next) {
    res.end(a); // [3]
});
```

[1] `foo` is fetched immediately, as are any things `foo` `require`s, `module.exports` gets assigned to `a`.

[2] when this callback is invoked, we just tell `express`, do nothing, skip me and go to the next middleware.

[3] assuming `a` has some string assigned to `module.exports` within `foo`, it is perfectly accessible to requests made to `/foo`.

What you need to take into account is that these functions are just callbacks `express` keeps references to, and it invokes them when it arrives at a particular one of them. They are processed in order, until you call `next`, which waterfalls into the next middleware. If you don't call `next`, you should be ending the response.

*I'm not sure exactly how you think the lifecycle works, but it probably doesn't work the way you think. Node just sits around and waits for requests to come in, and then processes them one at a time, it never stops, and it never really "reloads" anything.*

Comment: So when an Express.js app is initialized, the `require()` calls are executed and cached? This happens even before a single HTTP request to the app is made? Doesn't the `app.js` run for every HTTP request? I don't think that the objects returned from `require()` calls are shared between HTTP requests. Rather, for each request new objects are created from the `require()` calls inside `app.js`.

Comment: No, `require` calls are interpreted as they are met in code paths, see my update for details. The [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) chesles linked to is also a pretty good resource to understanding all this.

Comment: After reading your update, it seems to me that `app.js` is executed only once, during initialization, before any HTTP requests are made. Is that correct? It kind-of makes sense now LOL

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Once you call `.listen(port, done)`, then it can start processing requests, but nothing is ever reloaded, unless you purposely delete modules from the cache or something.

Comment: Does that mean that global variables of `app.js` are shared between HTTP requests? (That would be cool!). For example, I could have a "shared.js" file which is just `exports.stuff = {}`, then require it in "app.js": `var shared = require('./shared');`. Next, I could in the `app.get('/thing'` callback do: `shared.stuff.thing = 123;`, and in the `app.get('/foo'` callback use `shared.stuff.thing`, even though those are 2 different requests from 2 different visitors.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Although not very useful, and kind of dangerous.

Comment: Also keep in mind that, in the world of Node, variables are _local to the module they're declared in, if they're declared on the topmost level_, they are only truly global if you assign them to the `global` object (e.g `global.foo = foo.bar.bind(foo);`)

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching):

> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

After the first load, the only extra overhead in the call to `require` is resolving the path to the file. Conventionally, all calls to `require` are placed at the top of the file.

Comment: It think this is meant in the context of performing multiple `require()` calls for the same path during the same program execution (i.e. within `app.js`). So, if you happen to have multiple require-calls within your `app.js`, only the first call will generate the object and the subsequent calls will use that object instead of generating a new object.

Comment: Yes. It also applies to a server request handler - essentially a function that is called multiple times during the same program execution.

Comment: Now that I know that the "app.js" file (= the Express.js web app) is executed only once (and not once per HTTP request), my issue has been taken care of :-D. I can put a bunch of `require()`s at the top of "app.js" and they will be called only once during init.